# Write a small archiving program that stores students' names along with the grade that they are in

Tags: java, object-oriented, programming-challenge, design-patterns

**Problem:**

> Write a small archiving program that stores students' names along with
>   the grade that they are in.
>
> In the end, you should be able to:
>
> - Add a student's name to the roster for a grade.
> - Get a list of all students enrolled in a grade.
> - Get a sorted list of all students in all grades. Grades should sort    as 1, 2, 3, etc., and students within a grade should be sorted
>     alphabetically by name.
>
> Note that all our students only have one name. (It's a small town,
>   what do you want?)

**Code:**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;


public class School {
  private final Map<Integer, Set<String>> studentRecord;

  public School() {
    studentRecord = new HashMap<>();
  }

  public void add(String name, int grade) {
    Set<String> names = Optional.ofNullable(
        studentRecord.get(grade)).orElse(new TreeSet<>());
    names.add(name);
    studentRecord.put(grade, names);
  }

  public Map<Integer, Set<String>> db() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(studentRecord);
  }

  public Set<String> grade(int grade) {
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(Optional.ofNullable(
        studentRecord.get(grade)).orElse(new TreeSet<>()));
  }

  public Map<Integer, List<String>> sort() {
    Map<Integer, List<String>> studentGradeMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Set<String>> entry : studentRecord.entrySet()) {
      studentGradeMap.put(entry.getKey(), new ArrayList<>(entry.getValue()));
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(studentGradeMap);
  }
}
```

**Test suite:**

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class SchoolTest {
  private final School school = new School();

  @Test
  public void startsWithNoStudents() {
    assertThat(school.db()).isEmpty();
  }

  @Test
  public void addsStudents() {
    school.add("Aimee", 2);
    assertThat(school.db().get(2)).contains("Aimee");
  }

  @Test
  public void addsMoreStudentsInSameGrade() {
    final int grade = 2;
    school.add("James", grade);
    school.add("Blair", grade);
    school.add("Paul", grade);

    assertThat(school.db().get(grade)).hasSize(3).contains("James", "Blair", "Paul");
  }

  @Test
  public void addsStudentsInMultipleGrades() {
    school.add("Chelsea", 3);
    school.add("Logan", 7);

    assertThat(school.db()).hasSize(2);
    assertThat(school.db().get(3)).hasSize(1).contains("Chelsea");
    assertThat(school.db().get(7)).hasSize(1).contains("Logan");
  }

  @Test
  public void getsStudentsInAGrade() {
    school.add("Franklin", 5);
    school.add("Bradley", 5);
    school.add("Jeff", 1);
    assertThat(school.grade(5)).hasSize(2).contains("Franklin", "Bradley");
  }

  @Test
  public void getsStudentsInEmptyGrade() {
    assertThat(school.grade(1)).isEmpty();
  }

  @Test
  public void sortsSchool() {
    school.add("Jennifer", 4);
    school.add("Kareem", 6);
    school.add("Christopher", 4);
    school.add("Kyle", 3);
    Map<Integer, List<String>> sortedStudents = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
    sortedStudents.put(6, Arrays.asList("Kareem"));
    sortedStudents.put(4, Arrays.asList("Christopher", "Jennifer"));
    sortedStudents.put(3, Arrays.asList("Kyle"));

    assertThat(school.sort()).isEqualTo(sortedStudents);
  }
}
```

**Note:**

As personal opinion I found this exercise horrible, the implementation was not that difficult but the API expected in the test suite were horrible. The client knows more than expected of the internal date structure used and of course Law of Demeter.

**Design Decisions:**

The question expected some kind of mapping of grades with names so, the choice for `Map` seemed obvious to me. Now, the expectation was to have a sorted list of names so, I had two choices:

- Have a **unique** list of names and keep them sorted if any modifications are made.
- Have a sorted set which takes care of the above problem. But as the client code expected the List in the `sort` method I have to do the conversion there.

**Questions:**

Today while coding I got one weird issue, I was confused about the data structure for `studentRecord` so I toggled between `Set` and `List` couple of times, but every time that change was propagated everywhere in the code for eg: return type and all, is it some code smell or bad OO design?

Last but not least I kept the `studentRecord` field final and every public methods returns immutable view of it to prevent any unintentional modifications.

Reference: [Exercism](http://exercism.io/exercises/java/grade-school/readme)

Comment: A Set isn't the same as a List, that's why it was screaming about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments about the code itself first:

#### Use Java 8 constructs

```
public void add(String name, int grade) {
    Set<String> names = Optional.ofNullable(studentRecord.get(grade)).orElse(new TreeSet<>());
    names.add(name);
    studentRecord.put(grade, names);
}
```

can simply be written

```
public void add(String name, int grade) {
    studentRecord.computeIfAbsent(grade, k -> new TreeSet<>()).add(name);
}
```

The method [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) will return the current mapping for the given key. If there is no mapping,  it will store as value for the key the result of invoking the given mapping function and return it.

---

In the same way, your `grade` method is:

```
public Set<String> grade(int grade) {
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(Optional.ofNullable(studentRecord.get(grade)).orElse(new TreeSet<>()));
}
```

You could just use the method [`getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) to return a default value:

```
public Set<String> grade(int grade) {
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(studentRecord.getOrDefault(grade, Collections.emptySet()));
}
```

In this case, the default value is [`Collections.emptySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptySet--) which is a pre-existent (and pre-allocated) empty set.

#### About unmodifiable constructs

Your `db()` method currently does:

```
public Map<Integer, Set<String>> db() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(studentRecord);
}
```

It returns an unmodifiable view of the current map. This is great as it prevents the caller from adding entries inside it and modifying the internal data structure. However... the set it still modifiable. Consider:

```
School school = new School();
school.add("James", 2);
school.db().get(2).add("Blair");
System.out.println(school.db());
```

This will modify the students stored for the grade 2: the map was never modified but its entries were.

This tells us that you will be better off by returning a new map completely, containing a new list:

```
public Map<Integer, Set<String>> db() {
    return studentRecord.entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> new TreeSet<>(e.getValue())));
}
```

---

Now, about the design.

There are indeed two choices about having a `List` or a `Set` for the names:

- `List`: we know from the problem description that there won't be duplicate names (*Note that all our students only have one name*) so this isn't a problem. We know also that our `School` has two methods to dump its data: one in "raw" form `db()` and one in sorted form `sort()`. If we use a list, we'll explicitely need to sort in the latter method.
- `SortedSet`: This makes sure that there won't be any dupes but this was already a pre-requisite. It internally keeps the data sorted so both method `db()` and `sort()` will return exactly the same data.

All in all, I don't think there is a "best" choice. From the public methods exposed by `School`, I would maybe prefer a `List`: this way, the `db()` method can directly return its unsorted data, very quicky; whereas the `sort()` method will need to do more work to actually sort and return that.

However, you're right that juggling between a `Set` and a `List` changes the method return type. However, there is a way to prevent that: return an `Iterable`. It sends the client the signal that all it can do with it is iterate over the results, and nothing else. And since both `Set` and `List` are `Iterable`, it directly solves the problem: you won't need to change the public API if you decide to switch.

(And in case the ugly client still wants to downcast the `Iterable`, we still need make sure to return true unmodifiable constructs.)

Comment: For immutablility what do you say about this http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html ?

Comment: @CodeYogi Yes, that would be a good choice if you want to use 3rd party APIs.

Comment: Hmm, its not about API its about idea. So, whenever possible I should return immutable collections right?

Comment: @CodeYogi Ah sorry I misunderstood! Yes, if you need to return maps or collections, it is best to make them immutable (and not just unmodifiable). But note that more often that not, there is actually no reason to return them, and you can instead delegate calls to them (this keeps the data structure internal without exposing it to the client)

Comment: Ya, as I said earlier that it was a major flaw in the exercise itself.

Comment: By using the `SortedSet` I am avoiding the overhead of sorting again and again, if we know sorting is a costly process.

Comment: @CodeYogi This is true: it depends where the cost of sorting needs to be: only in the `sort` method or distributed anytime an element is added. Both are indeed possible.